# GetTouch(0) and GetTouch(1) are interchanging in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, touch

Guys I have created a TouchJoystick.cs but I have a problem in it. When I tap and hold on left side of the screen it says GetTouch(0) is in left side…ok so far so good, but when I simultaneously tap and hold on the right side of the screen it only sometimes says that GetTouch(1) is in the right side (which is what I want)… but sometimes It says GetTouch(0) is in the right side (or in other words though I was still holding down GetTouch(0) in the left side somehow it transfered it to the right side and made left side GetTouch(1) ) … please help me.. here’s the code.
http://pastebin.com/Rp8RqAfQ
And here are the two images needed for the script,
Joypad Base
http://s5.postimg.org/3tqq6wsgz/Joypad_Base1.png 
and JoyPad Stick 
I am not able to Upload :( its not allowing me.

Comment: GetTouch is related to touch count. You need to check every touch if it is left or right. If user touch right side before touching left sideGetTouch(0) is right side.

Comment: @BarışÇırıka "If user touch right side before touching left sideGetTouch(0) is right side." Nope it is not working like this... that's my problem.. even if the user touches the right side while touching and holding the left side which is GetTouch(0).. the right side sometimes get switched to GetTouch(0) and the left side which is Gettouch(0) gets overrided into Gettouch(1).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it working... 
Here is the completed script http://hastebin.com/icujaxeqik.avrasm